# can anyone please tell me what is the difference between Inversion of Control (IOC) and Dependency Injection (DI) in spring?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'am seriously figuring out this for the last one week and continuously keep on reading articles and blogs so that I can understand the difference in the very leman language and terms so that I can understand easily!!!!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency injection is simply about depending on an abstract interface and passing a concrete implementation of that interface to your class through the constructor or a setter method. This allows you to use a different concrete implementation without changing your class. This is useful, for instance for testing.

IoC is also known as the Hollywood principle: don't call us, we call you. In this case a framework defines an interface and the application provides the concrete implementation. This helps to limit dependencies between classes. IoC is often implemented using dependency injection, but it's not a hard requirement.